# $\frac{\partial f_i}{x_j}=\frac{\partial f_j}{x_i}\implies(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ is a gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was reading a solution when I came across this statement.

> So $$\frac{\partial f_i}{x_j}=\frac{\partial f_j}{x_i}.$$ Then there exists a differentiable function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=f_i$.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 2):

The following proofs assume 2 variables.

#### Proof of necessary condition:

If $(f_i, f_j)$ is the gradient of a function $F$, it means that:

$$
\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x_i}} = f_i \\
\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x_j}} = f_j
$$

Now, if $F$ has continuous second partial derivatives, then according to [Clairaut's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Clairaut.27s_theorem):

$$
\frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{x_i}\partial{x_j}} = \frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{x_j}\partial{x_i}}
$$

Therefore:

$$
\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{x_j}} = \frac{\partial{f_j}}{\partial{x_i}}
$$

#### Proof of sufficient condition:

The function $F$, if it exists, has the property:

$$
\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x_i}} = f_i
$$

By integrating with $x_j$ constant:

$$
F = \int_{x_{i_0}}^{x_i} f_i \, dx_i + R(x_j) \tag{1}
$$

Now take partial derivatives of both sides with respect to $x_j$:

$$
\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x_j}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_j}}\int_{x_{i_0}}^{x_i} f_i \, dx_i + R'(x_j) = f_j
$$

Using [differentiation under integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign):

$$
\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x_j}} = \int_{x_{i_0}}^{x_i} \frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{x_j}} \, dx_i + R'(x_j) = f_j
$$

Using the assumption that $\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$:

$$
\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x_j}} = \int_{x_{i_0}}^{x_i} \frac{\partial{f_j}}{\partial{x_i}} \, dx_i + R'(x_j) = f_j
$$

Which we can write as:

$$
\left. f_j \right|_{x_{i_0}}^{x_i} + R'(x_j) = f_j
$$

Therefore:

$$
R'(x_j) = f_j(x_{i_0}, x_j)
$$

And:

$$
R(x_j) = \int_{x_{j_0}}^{x_j} f_j \, dx_j
$$

Plug in back into (1):
$$
F = \int_{x_{i_0}}^{x_i} f_i \, dx_i + \int_{x_{j_0}}^{x_j} f_j \, dx_j
$$

Therefore, we have shown that $F$ exists.

Comment: Isn't that the converse of what I asked?

Comment: @nael - I added proofs for both necessary and sufficient conditions.

Comment: You changed $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{\color{Blue}j}}$ to $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{\color{Red}i}}$ inside the integral (I'd specify which line but you only tagged a single equation!), and strangely you seem to operate as if there are only two variables, $x_i$ and $x_j$, when really there are $n$ variables: $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, with $i$ and $j$ merely indexing them.

Comment: @anon:  The change inside the integral is using the assumption that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \displaystyle\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}$, so I think that's ok.

Comment: @anon - Jason's explanation is right. And yes my proof assumes 2 variables.

Comment: Ah, my bad! I suppose you want to employ this recursively for the multivariable form...

Comment: @anon - Clarified that in the answer. Is there a way to automatically number equations? Seems to be disabled here.

Comment: Nothing automatic. You have to type \tag{1}, \tag{2}, \tag{3} etc. all manually :/